# Installing Windows 7 Upgrade Based on Windows 2000 License - can it be done?

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2000, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I have a few PCs on which I have Windows 2000 Installed.
I have recently decided to upgrade to Windows 7 (Home or Pro) and noticed that the Upgrade packages are (obviously much cheaper).

Can I use the Upgrade to install Windows 7 on my machine (using the Windows 2000 License key)? I'm talking about format and install - not "upgrade" which I understand that is not supported. My question is is this OK license wise, and how to accomplish it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Windows 7 Upgrade Eligibility and Paths](http://www.softwarenewsdaily.com/2009/10/windows-7-upgrade-eligibility-and-paths):

> You are eligible to purchase an
>   upgrade to any version of Windows 7 if
>   you own any previous version of
>   Windows starting with XP or later.
>   Windows 98, 2000, and ME don’t qualify
>   you to purchase an upgrade. **If the PC
>   you want to install Windows 7 on has a
>   version of Windows older than XP, you
>   will need to purchase a full retail or
>   OEM version of Windows 7.**

So no, a Windows 2000 license doesn't qualify for an upgrade version of Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

No. Never. Servers are their own upgrade path. You could possibly move from 2000 via upgrades to 2008 R2 server, but not Win 7.That said, upgardes work one step at a time, and you did skip a LOT of steps, so the upgrade would not be cheaper, imho.

Basically, in your case you buy Windows 7.

Comment: Remember that Windows 2000 included a workstation edition. I agree that an upgrade part might be rather complex though.

Comment: Windows 2000 came in the Professional version which was for workstations and was the forerunner to Windows XP, and Server which were the server versions.

Comment: Exactly. Poster alks explicitly of 2000 SERVER, not 2000 Workstation. These still were different upgrade paths, as I said.

Comment: the only place server is mentioned is in a tag - it's not the worlds hardest thing to pick the wrong tag. The body of the question mentions PCs (rather than servers) and Home/Pro editions.. =)